# Auto Download a zip file from firefox using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I had a selenium script to download a file from a website and i have used these preferences to get out of getting the pop up on the final download of the file, still, i get this pop up on final end.
I don't need this pop-up and my zip file should auto download please help me with a solution.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/zip')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.update_preferences()
```

[Pop up Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYyYE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the "application/zip". Try this instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream") #I realy dont know why application/zip doesnt work here
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'F:\\drivers')



driver = webdriver.Firefox( firefox_profile = profile,executable_path='F:\\drivers\\geckodriver')

driver.get('https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.1/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64.zip"]').click()
```